# Ajax request to localhost php using jsonp not working

Tags: jquery, mysql, ajax, jsonp

Hi am using a Jquery to call a php script. The php script is located at `http://localhost:8080/getData.php` and it accesses a MySql database.

I am using a tomcat server setup on my pc with the server address of localhost:8080

I have looked at the ajax response data.status and it is 0

I have read about cross domain requests and know that this should not be a problem if i am using JSONp.

Any help would be much appreciated.

**The jquery part inside of my HTML i use to call an ajax function is below:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
   $.ajax({
       type:'GET',
       url:'http://localhost/getData.php',
       datatype:'jsonp',
       timeout: 5000,
       success: function(data){
           //data loaded
           alert('loaded');

       },
       error: function(data){
           // error on loading data
           alert('error');        
       }
    });
});
</script>
```

**The actual getData.php code is below:**

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/json');

$server = "127.0.0.1";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$database = "deals";

$con = mysql_connect($server, $username, $password) or die ("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($database, $con);

$sql = "SELECT area_id, name AS area_name, sector AS area_sector FROM deals.areas ORDER BY name";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die ("Query error: " . mysql_error());

$records = array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $records[] = $row;
}

mysql_close($con);

echo $_GET['jsoncallback'] . '(' . json_encode($records) . ');';
?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm seeing three issues:

1. Your PHP script is looking for a GET parameter called `jsoncallback`, but that's not the name that jQuery sends by default, which is `callback`. Either change your PHP to use `callback` instead:

   ```
   // Here ----v
   echo $_GET['callback'] . '(' . json_encode($records) . ');';
   ```

   ...or add this option to your [`ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) call to tell jQuery to use `jsoncallback` instead:

   ```
   jsonp: "jsoncallback",
   ```

   You can use the Network tab in your browser's development tools to inspect the call and see what the query string looks like, to make sure they match up.
2. You have a typo in your ajax options, you have `datatype:'jsonp'` instead of `dataType:'jsonp'` (the `T` in `dataType` must be upper case), so jQuery won't have been trying to do a JSON-P call at all, it will have tried XHR.
3. You've said in your question that the PHP page is at `http://localhost:8080/getData.php`, but the `url` you've given jQuery is `http://localhost/getData.php` (without the port).

Comment: Hi T.J Crowder, i'll try and give that a go when i am back home later on today. I am fairly new to this, have you done something similar to what i am doing? if so do you know of any links/tutorials on the web Many thanks for your response.

Comment: @user1907509: I don't know of a *specific* one, but there is no shortage of jQuery/JSON-P examples on the web. :-) I noticed a couple of other problems with your call and have updated the answer, hope it helps.

Comment: T.J Crowder i hav tried this and have been able to get a response from the php but the response is just the actual source code of the php and not the expected JSON data. Maybe im doing something wrong on the php side. Does the php script look correct?

Comment: @user1907509: Sounds like PHP isn't configured correctly on your web server.

Comment: @user1907509: Great! Glad that helped. Best,